# SMS receive with no notification

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I want to receive a sms in my app, but I don't want my Android to show a notification about that event. Algorithm:

1. Receive sms (it's ok)
2. If this is a sms with special content-format (for my app) - process it with my app and don't display a notification.
3. If this is a simple message - I don't want to process it, so a notification must be displayed.

I tried to use an ordered broadcast, but it doesn't help. Somewhere I read that SMS_RECEIVE's broadcast is not ordered, but I saw some apps, which can receive SMS without notify.

Does anyone can help me or show me the right way to solve this problem?

Calling `abortBroadcast()` in broadcast doesn't help

Answer (score 7):

set priority in your intent-filter
// in manifest

```
<intent-filter android:priority="100">  /*your receiver get high priority*/
```

// in broadcast receiver

```
 if (keyword_match)
      {
        // Stop it being passed to the main Messaging inbox
        abortBroadcast();
      }
```

Answer (score 5):

This should be possible by registering your app to receive SMS messages and then using abortBroadcast() when you detect your message has arrived.  You say abortBroadcast() doesn't work - is the SMS definitely getting handled by your SMS receiver?

For anybody else wanting to do this, read on...

First, declare the SMS receiver in your AndroidManifest.xml and make sure the app has permission to receive SMS messages.

```
 <receiver android:name="mypackage.SMSReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
   </intent-filter>
 </receiver>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

Here's some example code to handle the SMS messages:

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
  {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    Object[] pdus = (Object[])extras.get("pdus");
    for (Object pdu: pdus)
    {
      SmsMessage msg = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdu);

      String origin = msg.getOriginatingAddress();
      String body = msg.getMessageBody();

      // Parse the SMS body
      if (isMySpecialSMS)
      {
        // Stop it being passed to the main Messaging inbox
        abortBroadcast();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: While this does answer the question correctly, you should not do this. Other apps might want or need to receive the SMS_RECEIVED broadcast. Aborting it will disrupt 3rd party apps from running properly. This is a bad way to program.

Comment: Yes, I suppose I should add a disclaimer that it would generally be best to use Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) instead of a custom SMS approach. http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You should not do this. Other apps might want or need to receive the SMS_RECEIVED broadcast. Aborting it will disrupt 3rd party apps from running properly. This is a bad way to program. you should only abort broadcasts that you create, not system broadcasts. I don't know why the Android OS lets you do this.

Comment: Having a big problem with this. If GO SMS Pro is installed, they catch all messages (they have their priority at interger.maxvalue) and abort the broadcast to my app (and to any other). That really sucks and I don't see a workaround...

Comment: @Anton - You can't do anything about this except let your users know that they must turn that feature off in Go SMS Pro (This is what I have to do all the time).

Comment: At least for myself (for apps like LookOut for example, who depend on receiving sms messages in case they need to activate WiFi/GPS) I'm going to edit the Manifest of GO SMS and reinstall with a proper value...

Answer (score 0):

not sure if i know exactly what you are trying to do but from what i understand you just want to know how to not send a notification?

why cant you just do:

```
If(instance 2){
//do your processing
}else{
//send notification
}
```

if you mean you want to block the OS from broadcasting it then you might be out of luck because i dont believe you can do that

Comment: So, there is a default Android's app for SMS reading and writing. Let's call it "Messaging". When I receive a SMS the "Messaging" displays a notification about this event. I want my app (lets call it "P") to receive this message before "Messaging" would receive it. So, if this is a special SMS - I want "Messaging" not to process this sms. Simply, I want "Messaging" not to process some special SMS.

Answer (score 0):

yo need android:priority attribute for that to work

```
<intent-filter android:priority="1"> 
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing one  mistake,
because you fired abortBroadcast(); if your special message so the message broadcasting is aborted, therefore SMS notification is not Showing, and sms is not saving in Inbox,
You have to make your own Notification in "onRecive" if your special message is received.
Example:

```
      public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
      {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        Object[] pdus = (Object[])extras.get("pdus");
        for (Object pdu: pdus)
        {
          SmsMessage msg = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdu);

          String origin = msg.getOriginatingAddress();
          String body = msg.getMessageBody();

          // Parse the SMS body
          if (isMySpecialSMS)
          { // Stop it being passed to the main Messaging inbox
            abortBroadcast();
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "New Message (My Messaging app)", System.currentTimeMillis());
        // Uses the default lighting scheme
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
        // Will show lights and make the notification disappear when the presses it
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL | Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, SplashActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent =PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                new Intent(context, SplashActivity.class), 0);

        Log.i("Wakeup", "Display Wakeup");
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock((PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP), "Phone WakeUp");
        wakeLock.acquire();

        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "My Messaging App(New Message)",msg, pendingIntent);
        //notification.sound.
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notificationManager.notify(9999, notification);
          }
         else{
        //Continue Broadcasting to main android app
         }
        }
      }
    }
```

I hope this will solve your Problem