# Android and consume SMS

Tags: android, sms

I write application which will get data from received SMS. This is data only for application and I dont want to user can read this message. Is possible to consume SMS just after get data from them to prevent user from reading this SMS? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Consider to let the user see the SMS if he wants. Makes your app more trust-worthy, I think. And if you plan to even *send* SMS, you should definitely let the user know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a sms receiver see http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/15/android-listen-for-incoming-sms-messages/

Maybe you need also to delete the received sms.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is easy to do.  See my answer here for how to do this:
[SMS receive with no notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380192/sms-receive-with-no-notification/6103343#6103343)

Once you've confirmed that the SMS is one of your special ones, you just need to call `abortBroadcast()` to stop it going into the user's inbox:

```
    // Stop it being passed to the main Messaging inbox
    abortBroadcast();
```

You should also be aware that the SMS receiver will not intercept SMS messages sent to the user's Google Voice number, as by default those messages will be downloaded over the data connection and displayed by the Google Voice app.  If their Google Voice number is configured to forward the SMSs to the phone then those will be handled fine by the SMS receiver.