# Android: Receive silent sms?

Tags: java, android, sms, silent

I am currently coding an SMS-controlled GPS Tracker. 
Every time I send an SMS to the device it's handled like a normal sms (new message in inbox and notification), but these sms are just to control the app.

Is is possible to turn off notifications for these sms? I also don't want all these sms in my inbox folder...

Comment: You might find something useful here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380192/sms-receive-with-no-notification

Answer (score 2):

Create your Broadcast Receiver for Receiving SMS.
Set Intent Filter with highest priority.

```
<intent-filter android:priority="100"> 
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
```

In your receiver class, abortBroadcast() method, which will not notify for SMS.

And delete the currently received message.

Answer (score 0):

yes this is possible you need to use this method into the broadcast receiver at last

```
abortBroadcast();
```

This will cancel the broadcasting to the user.