# silently consuming an SMS on android?

Tags: android, sms

I wonder how would one 'consume' certain SMS messages that are received by an android device, based on custom criteria (content or sender, etc.). for this, I registered a subclass of BroadcastReceiver, which is fine, as it does get the SMS message. but the message is sent to the 'standard' SMS store as well.

would anyone know if it is possible to 'consume' the message? that is, remove it from the queue, and make sure that the 'standard' SMS handler does not receive it?

Comment: -1 No research effort, i found a solution in 1 minute that you could at least have tried and see if it works, see the comment below.

Comment: what comment below? :) I only see your comment...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380192/sms-receive-with-no-notification/6103343#6103343

Comment: thanks, indeed, the answer is there on the other thread. of course I tried abortBroadcast(); myself, but was the SMS queue is not a priority queue by default, it didn't work. but adding the following into the manifest makes it work, but turning the SMS queue into a priority queue:

`<intent-filter android:priority="1"> 
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
</intent-filter>`

Comment: There was an "answer" which i commented with the link. Got deleted in the meantime

Comment: yeah, well, whatever. complaining & referring to a non-existent 'solution post' is way -1 for me. with the same effort, you could have just pasted the result of your '1 minute search', and actually be helpful for a change.

Answer (score 2):

thanks for all the pointers.

the answer to the question is that one has to use abortBroadcast() in a BroadcastReceiver, but most importantly one has to turn the message queue into a priority queue, otherwise abortBroadcast() doesn't work. fortunately it is possible to do this in the manifest:

```
<intent-filter android:priority="1">
    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
</intent-filter>
```

note the `android:priority="1"` attribute in the intent-filter element.