# I want to stop sms notification in android phone

Tags: android, sms

I want to stop the sms messaging in android phone notification in android,

Please guide me regarding this.

Comment: Clarify that please. I'm not entirely sure what you want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SMS receive with no notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380192/sms-receive-with-no-notification)