# How to add code in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I am fairly new to Android programming and I'm doing my best to understand the tutorial. I have downloaded the sample code from [this link](http://msatpathy.wordpress.com/android/send-and-receiving-sms-%E2%80%93-in-android/).

Now I want to integrate the code from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380192/sms-receive-with-no-notification?rq=1). It says here to "declare the SMS receiver in your AndroidManifest.xml"

The code is:

```
 <receiver android:name="mypackage.SMSReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
   </intent-filter>
 </receiver>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

Here's the existing code from the sample file I downloaded under AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.smsTest"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".SMSTest"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS">
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS">
    </uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

Now my question is where to add the code (the first code above) into AndroidManifest.xml.

I tried to change this line:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
```

with this:

```
<action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
```

without luck.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: First of all, XML is not code, it's data.  Secondly, 10 seconds on Google.  http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.smsTest"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".SMSTest"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
<receiver android:name="mypackage.SMSReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
</application>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS">
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS">
</uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am facing new problem after editing the SmsReceiver.java. I just added the code `abortBroadcast();` below `Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` and it brought 3 errors like `Call requires API level 4 (current min is 1): android.telephony.SmsMessage#createFromPdu SmsReceiver.java /SMSTest/src/com/example/smsTest line 25 Android Lint Problem`

Comment: @jaypabs Please post a new question with the complete code an the errors you get so that I can give you an answer.

Comment: @jaypabs if any of these answers helped you you could give back reputation, by accepting an answer (click green tick on the left) and/or upvoting an answer (click orange up arrow on the left). Good luck with your work! maurizio

Comment: thanks. i already fix that problem. but when I send msg using the 2nd emulator the app crashes saying "Unfortunately, SMSTest has stopped." I have followed the with `abortBroadcast();`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the receiver as a 2nd item inside the application.  You don't replace the intent filter on the activity.  It should go between the  and  tags.

The manifest is really describing whats in your apk.  Your application will have 1 activity, SMSTest, that is launched from the launcher.  It also has 1 receiver which receives the intent SMS_RECEIVED.  So both parts need to be in there.  Make sense?