# Push Notification from one android device to another

Tags: android, push-notification

Here I am developing an android app which deals with housing complex.

In this app their are 2 kinds of users:

1. Builder/Complex Owner
2. Flat Owner.

Now here the Builder/Complex Owner can send push notification to flat owners.

How can I achieve that? Please help.

Here I cannot use G.C.M as G.C.M. is used for server side push messaging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to send device to device push notification using gcm.See [this](http://androidexample.com/Device_To_Device_Messaging_Using_Google_Cloud_Messaging_GCM_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=122&aaid=142) link.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is any other way. What you could do is to let the app send a push notification request to the server, then the server would issue the push notification through G.C.M. If you don't have a server available you could do it through text messages but be sure to have a good text messaging plan. You could possibly also use an existing service (for example Facebook) and send the messages through their API.

EDIT:
To do it via text messages: [SMS receive with no notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380192/sms-receive-with-no-notification/6103343#6103343). Again, make sure that you have a good text messaging plan if doing this. Sending an SMS to ten different people will count as ten different SMS messages.. If you have a lot of users it would probably be cheaper to get hold of an SMS server. But then again, you should just use G.C.M.

Comment: Actually Yes I have a server,but I dont want to use it over here.Gcm can be used to communicate between server and devices registered but not between two individual devices.Hence I cannot use GCM over here.

Comment: @android, not sure if that is possible. The problem is that the Flat Owners devices would need somewhere to look for new notifications. This is what the server would normally be used for. Without the server the devices would need to find the Builder/Complex Owners phone from anywhere. This would basically turn the Builder/Complex Owners phone into the server, which is not optimal. If your not looking to set up a underground torrent-like network of distributed notification deliveries then I'm not really sure how you would do it in a good way..