# Intercepting Incoming SMS in android using Delphi XE8

Tags: android, delphi, sms, telephony

I've made a Delphi XE8 app that tries to receive a notification when an SMS message arrives at the terminal. I'm reluctant to use a `TTimer` to scan the inbox periodically. I've used a [BroadCast Reciever](https://github.com/barisatalay/delphi-android-broadcast-receiver-component/tree/master/Demo), but when an SMS is received, my app crashes with the text:

> Unfortunately the App MYAPP1 has closed

PS: My SDK tops at 23.

*MANIFEST FILE*:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
        <activity android:name="com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity"
                android:label="%activityLabel%"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden"
                android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="%libNameValue%" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter> 
        </activity>
      <receiver android:name="com.embarcadero.notifications.FMXNotificationAlarm" />
        <receiver android:name="com.androidexample.broadcastreceiver.IncomingSms"> 
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

```pascal
type
  JTelephonySmsIntentsClass = interface(IJavaClass)      
    ['{73FFA042-DAE3-497F-B9D4-B7F1B178E941}']      
    function getMessagesFromIntent(...);      
    ...     
  end;      
      
  [JavaSignature('android/provider/Telephony/Sms/Intents')]      
  JTelephonySmsIntents = interface (IJavaInstance)              ['{42798E28-0E3A-4287-8EE9-606BB9D311B5}']      
  end;  

  TJTelephonySmsIntents = class(TJavaGenericImport<JTelephonySmsIntentsClass, JTelephonySmsIntents>) end;  

procedure BCRecvr(Context: JContext; Intent: JIntent);
var
  I: Integer;
  msgs: TJavaArray<JSmsMessage>;
  msg : JSmsMessage;
  newPhoneNumber, text : string;
begin
  if Intent.getActn.cmpareTo(TJTelephSmsIntents.JavaClass.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION) = 0 then
  begin
    msgs := TJTelephSmsIntents.JavaClass.getMessFromIntent(Intent);
    for I := 0 to msgs.Length - 1 do
    begin
      msg := msgs[i];
      newPhoneNumber := JStringToString(msg.getOriginatingAddress);
      text := JStringToString(msg.getDisplayMessageBody);
      Memo1.Lines.Add(newPhoneNumber + ': ' + text);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Seems related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5380192/33732. Configure an `SMS_RECEIVED` intent, and then don't call `abortBroadcast`.

Comment: Not at all. That post is on the topic of stopping the event from passing to other apps, and it is on JAVA. My question is regarding how to receive the "NEW_SMS" arrived with a Delphi XE8 App.

Comment: The answer is the same as for Java. There is no built-in mechanism; you have to register for the intent with the OS whether it's Java or Delphi or something else.

Comment: Yes Ken, that is what I need to do, hence my question: "How"? Can anyone post some snippets?

Comment: Don't you register the intent with the manifest?

Comment: Yes I did. This is the code I have so far. When I run my app and an SMS enters, the app crashes with SegFault:

Comment: Also... Why the downvote? who enjoys downvoting questions? not helpful at all...

Comment: @Fernando please don't put so much code in comments. Next time, edit your question instead. I have done it for you this time.  That being said, you have a broadcast receiver handler, but did you register it so Android knows to call it?

Comment: @Fernando recent versions of Delphi have a `TMessageManager` for handling messages in a platform-agnostic fashion. See [Sending and Receiving Messages Using the RTL](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Sending_and_Receiving_Messages_Using_the_RTL). Android Broadcasts can be received as `TMessageReceivedNotification` messages.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sorry for the in-comment code, As you can see I'm new to StackO. I'll look into that site and System.Messaging Unit, thank you very much!!

Comment: @RemyLebeau Im reading the [doc](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Sending_and_Receiving_Messages_Using_the_RTL), and got to a dead end. I see how `TMsgMan` can register to intercept runtime messages, but cannot find how to intercept an _incomming SMS message_ and its content. help!

Comment: I've used a [BroadCast Reciever](https://github.com/barisatalay/delphi-android-broadcast-receiver-component/tree/master/Demo), but when an SMS is recieved, my app crashes with the text: "Unfortunately the App MYAPP1 has closed".

Comment: When run in the debugger from the IDE, where does the crash occur? What is the exception that arises? What does logcat show relating to the issue at the point of failure (which you can see by running $(ANDROIDSDK)\tools\monitor.bat)?
Shouldn't your `msgs` variable be a `TJavaObjectArray` of `JSmsMessage`? Should the import unit not declare `getMessagesFromIntent` as using the `cdecl`calling convention? Please be more specific about the nature of the issue, assuming there is still an issue.

Comment: The debugger simply gives a segfault and no break points inside the BCRecvr function are executed, giving me the impression that some memory is miss-assigned or miss-allocated during the capturing of the OnRecieve event, because the app works fine until an sms is recieved and then it crashes. (I inserted a break at the first line of the OnRecieved function but the CPU's PC didn't even get there.